# Handling C++ libraries include with Git

Tags: c++, git, dll, header, lib

After hours of googling I am surprised to not find this question asked before so I ask it!

We are switching from an old source control system to Git and so we are trying to improve our sources management design at the same time. We are working with C++ on Windows only.

We have several applications (let's call them **App1**, **App2** and **App3**) that are using some DLLs that we build ourselves (let's call them **Dll1** and **Dll2**). So our applications need the *header* file and the *.lib* file of each DLL it's using. For example, if **App1** wants to use **Dll1**, it needs *Dll1.h* and *Dll1.lib*. Each App or DLL are of course in a different Git project.

Currently with the old system, we have a script that "copy" the *.h* and the *.lib* from the DLL to the App in the correct version (using the SHA of the desired commit). **App1** in version 1.0 can copy a different *Dll1.h* and *Dll1.lib* from **App1** in version 2.0. That's not very satisfying because each time you checkout your repo from a version to another, you have to launch the script again (or it can even not compile).

Another solution could be to use submodules (we already use them for shared code between our apps) but it would force us to include the whole DLLs projects into each app, which is an horrible  perspective! We only need the *.h* and *.lib*... I have imagined a solution to have the *.h* and *.lib* alone in a submodule, included in the DLL, and the Apps, like:

```
Dll1
|- dll1.cpp
|- dll1.h
|- ...
|- header_and_lib
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|- .git (submodule)
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|- dll1.h
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|- dll1.lib

App1
|- app1.cpp
|- app1.h
|- ...
|- Dll1
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|- .git (submodule)
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|- dll1.h
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|- dll1.lib
```

But that's ugly, the code organisation should not be designed by the way you handle them with Git...

Does anyone one know a better solution for this kind of need?

Comment: Git is not inteneded to handle binary files such as .lib and .dll. Most right way to handle header files of the library and its source code files, instead of dll or lib. This libraries should be the seaprate project and may be included to the main project as submodules.

Comment: The common solution is to use some other system than git for storing (binary) artifacts, and a pre-build step to retrieve them. Another option might be [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/), which stores large files outside of the git repo so you don't need to lug around all versions all the time.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Ok, so let's forget the .lib and focus on the .h file. How can I include it as a submodule without bringing all the other source files that I don't need ?

Comment: You can't—or, you can treat the `.h` file as its own separate submodule, independent of the submodule that holds the library source, but nobody does that because it's a management nightmare. Just include the `.h` file *in* the generated artifact, generated by copying (vs the .lib / .dll file which is generated by running the linking software).

Comment: Yes, that was my first idea but yes that's ugly and not easy to manage. We will have unfortunately to keep the script system... That's a shame git doesn't handle this kind of situation, which should not be that rare!